# how to copy a large redis key and values?

Tags: caching, kubernetes, redis

How do I copy a key which has large number of values into a another key in redis. for eg.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
 1) "ProdCache"
```

`127.0.0.1:6379> hkeys "ProdCache"` <-- has 1000s of values

I am trying to copy all 1000s of ProdCache values into a new key, say "TestCache". I have tried with Dump but its spitting a very large output that I couldn't use restore. Appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: You can use HSCAN and HSET to copy field by field

Comment: I think that s too cumbersome for the large number of fields